# Examples of apache math optimization

Tags: apache, mathematical-optimization, solver, quadratic, nonlinear-optimization

I have a simple optimization problem and am looking for java software for that.

The Apache math optimization software looks just like what I want but I cant find documentation to suit my needs (where those needs are to useful to a beginner / non maths professional!)

Does anyone know of a worked, simple, example?

In case it helps, the problem is that I want to find the max r where

```
r1 = s1 * m1

r2 = s2 * m2
```

and there are some constraints and formula for defining the relationship between the variables. The Excel Solver works fine for this problem. I got LPSolve working great, but this problem requires a multiplication of s and m, so I understand LPSolve cant help as this makes the problem non linear.

Answer (score 1):

I recently ported the derivative-free non-linear constrained optimization code COBYLA2 to Java. Since it does not explicitly rely on derivatives, the algorithm may require quite a few iterations for larger problems. Nonetheless, you are able to formulate your problem with both a non-linear objective function and (potentially) non-linear constraints.

You can read more about it and download the source code from [here](https://github.com/cureos/jcobyla).

Comment: @Ribeye, you may have been able to workaround this issue by now, but if not I hope you will find the above answer useful for your work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a simple Java-based NLP solver. (I did find an example of Quadratic programming (QP) in **Apache Math Works**, but it doesn't qualify since you asked for a non-math professional example.)

I have two suggestions for you to solve your non-linear program:

1.. **Excel**'s `Solver` does have the ability to tackle non-linear problems. (Don't use LPSOLVE.) In fact, NLP is the default mode in Solver.

Here are two links to using Excel to solve NLPs:  Example 1 - [Step by step Solver walk-through that covers NLP](http://sites.google.com/site/decisionmodeling/Home/mp/lp/excel-solver) and 
Example 2 - [A General Neural network example in Excel](http://www.sunfinedata.com/data_analysis/excel-data_analysis/use-excel-solver-to-solve-non-linear-problem-solution-of-general-neural-network/)

Also for Excel, I like Paul Jensen's (utexas) **[ORMM Add-in's](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/excel/index.html)**. 
He has a module called ***[Teach NLP](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/methods/unit/nonlinear/subunits/teach_nlp/index.html)***. *[Chapter 10](http://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/ORMM/frontpage/ch_xls/index.html)* of his book deals with NLP and is available from his site.

2.. If you are going to be doing even some amount of *data analysis*, then I recommend investing a few hours to download and **learn the basics of R**.
R has [numerous packages and libraries for optimization](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html). `optim()` and `nlme` are relavant for solving non-linear programs.

Just for completeness, I mention **SAS**, **MATLAB** and **CPLEX** as other options. If you have access to any of these, they all do a very good job with solving non-linear programs.

Hope these pointers help.

Comment: Ram, thanks for excellent reply - R could be great - I did not know it did optimisation. Unfortunately I dont have enough credibility to bump you credibility (but that is just a simple reflection on my life general I suspect).

Comment: @Ribeye Don't worry about reps etc. Welcome to SO. I'm glad that the information helped.